# LevelDB data broken when program core or force killed?

Tags: leveldb

our game server use LevelDB as data-cache.

Recently, We found a serious problem:

**When server had a deadlock, we kill is use `kill -9`, some data in LevelDB are broken.**

So, I have two doubt:

1. Why data broken? I am sure my data had write back to LevelDB?
2. Someway to repair broken LevelDB ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About first questions:

- Use WriteBatch-es (aka atomic operations)
- Use Synchronous writes

Read [this](http://leveldb.googlecode.com/git-history/1.17/doc/index.html) article (sections Atomic Updates and Synchronous Writes). Seems like you don't do it.

About second questions: use backups :D ALWAYS USE BACKUPS!